# Separating my backbone model, view and collections into folders

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I was told that my project should have a separation of model, views and collections within their respective folders. This should be an easy fix but I am not sure how to do this and have my code still runable.

Here is my JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function() {

    var Food = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: {
            title: 'no information found',
            brand: 'no information found',
            calories: 'no information found',
        }
    });

    var AllFoods = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
        model: Food,
        url: "https://blinding-torch-8751.firebaseio.com/allfoods"

    });
    var Breakfast = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
        model: Food,
        url: "https://blinding-torch-8751.firebaseio.com/breakfast"

    });
    var Lunch = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
        model: Food,
        url: "https://blinding-torch-8751.firebaseio.com/lunch"

    });
    var Dinner = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
        model: Food,
        url: "https://blinding-torch-8751.firebaseio.com/dinner"

    });
    var Snack = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
        model: Food,
        url: "https://blinding-torch-8751.firebaseio.com/snack"

    });



    var SearchList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        initialize: function() {
            this.bind("reset", function(model, options) {
                console.log("Inside event");
                console.log(model);
            });
        },

        //** 1. Function "parse" is a Backbone function to parse the response properly
        parse: function(response) {
            //** return the array hits inside response, when returning the array
            //** we let Backone populate this collection
            return response.hits;
        }

    });


    var App = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: 'body',

        events: {
            "input #searchBox": "prepCollection",
            "click #listing li": "track",
            "click #add": "addClicked",
            "click #remove": "removeClicked"

        },

        initialize: function() {
            //set up variables used more globally
            this.foodid = "";
            this.model = new SearchList();
            this.foods = new AllFoods();
            this.breakfastlist = new Breakfast();
            this.lunchlist = new Lunch();
            this.dinnerlist = new Dinner();
            this.snacklist = new Snack();
            this.$total = $('#total span');
            this.$list = $('#listing');
            this.$instruct = $('#instruct');
            this.$tracked = $('#tracked');
            //code to respond to changes in the collections
            this.listenTo(this.foods, 'add', this.rendertracked);
            this.listenTo(this.foods, 'remove', this.rendertracked);
            this.listenTo(this.breakfastlist, 'add', this.renderbreakfast);
            this.listenTo(this.breakfastlist, 'remove', this.renderbreakfast);
            this.listenTo(this.lunchlist, 'add', this.renderlunch);
            this.listenTo(this.lunchlist, 'remove', this.renderlunch);
            this.listenTo(this.dinnerlist, 'add', this.renderdinner);
            this.listenTo(this.dinnerlist, 'remove', this.renderdinner);
            this.listenTo(this.snacklist, 'add', this.rendersnack);
            this.listenTo(this.snacklist, 'remove', this.rendersnack);
            //code to not fire off a request right away
            this.prepCollection = _.debounce(this.prepCollection, 1000);

        },

        addClicked: function(e) {
            var $target = $(e.currentTarget).parent();
            var $selected = $target.find('#mySelect').val();
            var location = $target.attr('data-id');
            //tracks the model selected in all of the collections
            var currentFood = this.foods.get(location);
            var currentBreakfast = this.breakfastlist.get(location);
            var currentLunch = this.lunchlist.get(location);
            var currentDinner = this.dinnerlist.get(location);
            var currentSnack = this.snacklist.get(location);
            //provides the html for the view
            var currenthtml = currentFood.get('html');

            switch ($selected) {

                //case statements make sure model is added to the proper meal collection
                //if elseif statements insure that no other collection except tracked has the same id-No duplicates
                case 'Breakfast':
                    this.breakfastlist.create(currentFood);

                    if (currentLunch) {
                        this.lunchlist.remove(currentLunch);
                    } else if (currentDinner) {
                        this.dinnerlist.remove(currentDinner);
                    } else if (currentSnack) {
                        this.snacklist.remove(currentSnack);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Lunch':
                    this.lunchlist.create(currentFood)

                    if (currentBreakfast) {
                        this.breakfastlist.remove(currentBreakfast);
                    } else if (currentDinner) {
                        this.dinnerlist.remove(currentDinner);
                    } else if (currentSnack) {
                        this.snacklist.remove(currentSnack);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Dinner':
                    this.dinnerlist.create(currentFood);

                    if (currentBreakfast) {
                        this.breakfastlist.remove(currentBreakfast);
                    } else if (currentLunch) {
                        this.lunchlist.remove(currentLunch);
                    } else if (currentSnack) {
                        this.snacklist.remove(currentSnack);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Snack':
                    this.snacklist.create(currentFood);

                    if (currentBreakfast) {
                        this.breakfastlist.remove(currentBreakfast);
                    } else if (currentLunch) {
                        this.lunchlist.remove(currentLunch);
                    } else if (currentDinner) {
                        this.dinnerlist.remove(currentDinner);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    alert("Error: try again");

            }



        },

        removeClicked: function(e) {
            var $target = $(e.currentTarget).parent();
            var removeid = $target.attr('data-id');
            //tracks the models in all of the collections
            var modelRemoved = this.foods.get(removeid);
            var breakfastRemoved = this.breakfastlist.get(removeid);
            var lunchRemoved = this.lunchlist.get(removeid);
            var dinnerRemoved = this.dinnerlist.get(removeid);
            var snackRemoved = this.snacklist.get(removeid);

            this.foods.remove(modelRemoved);
            //remove the model if it exists in a collection
            if (breakfastRemoved) {
                this.breakfastlist.remove(breakfastRemoved);
            } else if (lunchRemoved) {
                this.lunchlist.remove(lunchRemoved);
            } else if (dinnerRemoved) {
                this.dinnerlist.remove(dinnerRemoved);
            } else if (snackRemoved) {
                this.snacklist.remove(snackRemoved);
            }
        },

        prepCollection: function() {
            var name = $('input').val();
            var newUrl = "https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/" + name + "?results=0%3A20&cal_min=0&cal_max=50000&fields=item_name,brand_name,item_id,nf_calories&appId=26952a04&appKey=33b9262901d0068d4895736b5af19805";

            //populate the collection with models and provide instruction html
            if (name == "") {
                this.$list.html("")
                this.$instruct.html("")
            } else {
                this.$instruct.html("Click On A Food Item To Track It");
                this.model.url = newUrl;
                this.model.fetch({
                    success: function(response, xhr) {
                        console.log("Inside success");
                        console.log(response.toJSON());
                    },
                    error: function(errorResponse) {
                        console.log(errorResponse)
                    }
                });
                this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);
            }

        },

        track: function(e) {

            var $target = $(e.currentTarget);
            var item_name = $target.attr('data-name');
            var brand_name = $target.attr('data-brand');
            var calorieString = $target.attr('data-calories');
            var calorieAmt = parseFloat(calorieString);
            this.foodid = this.foodid + "1";

            var chooseday = '<form>What meal was this part of?: <select id="mySelect"> <option value="Breakfast">Breakfast</option><option value="Lunch">Lunch</option><option value="Dinner">Dinner</option><option value="Snack">Snack</option></select></form><button id="add" type="button">Add To Meal</button><button id="remove" type="button">Remove From Tracked</button>';

            var trackedhtml = '<li' + ' data-id=' + '"' + this.foodid + '"' + "<strong>" + item_name + '</strong>' + ' (' + brand_name + ')' + ' - ' + calorieAmt + ' Calories' + chooseday + '</li>'


            this.foods.create({
                id: this.foodid,
                title: item_name,
                brand: brand_name,
                calories: calorieAmt,
                html: trackedhtml
            });

        },

        rendertracked: function() {
            var total = 0;
            var trackedhtml = '';
            //resets the foodid variable when collection is empty to prevent long id names
            if (this.foods.length == 0) {
                this.foodid = ""
            };

            this.foods.each(function(food) {
                trackedhtml = trackedhtml + food.get('html');
                total += food.get('calories');
            }, this)
            this.$tracked.html(trackedhtml);
            this.$total.html(total);

        },
        renderbreakfast: function() {
            var total = 0;
            var breakfasthtml = '';

            this.breakfastlist.each(function(dish) {
                breakfasthtml = breakfasthtml + dish.get('html');
                total += dish.get('calories');
            }, this)
            $('#breakfast').html(breakfasthtml);
            $('#totalbreak span').html(total);


        },
        renderlunch: function() {
            var total = 0;
            var lunchtml = '';

            this.lunchlist.each(function(dish) {
                lunchtml = lunchtml + dish.get('html');
                total += dish.get('calories');
            }, this)
            $('#lunch').html(lunchtml);
            $('#totalunch span').html(total);
        },
        renderdinner: function() {
            var total = 0;
            var dinnerhtml = '';

            this.dinnerlist.each(function(dish) {
                dinnerhtml = dinnerhtml + dish.get('html');
                total += dish.get('calories');
            }, this)
            $('#dinner').html(dinnerhtml);
            $('#totaldinner span').html(total);
        },
        rendersnack: function() {
            var total = 0;
            var snackhtml = '';

            this.snacklist.each(function(dish) {
                snackhtml = snackhtml + dish.get('html');
                total += dish.get('calories');
            }, this)
            $('#snack').html(snackhtml);
            $('#totalsnack span').html(total);
        },

        render: function() {
            var terms = this.model;
            var wordhtml = '';
            terms.each(function(term) {
                wordhtml = wordhtml + '<li' + ' data-name=' + '"' + term.get('fields')['item_name'] + '"' + ' data-brand=' + '"' + term.get('fields')['brand_name'] + '"' + ' data-calories=' + '"' + term.get('fields')['nf_calories'] + '"' + '>' + "<strong>" + term.get('fields')["item_name"] + '</strong>' + ' (' + term.get('fields')["brand_name"] + ')' + ' - ' + term.get('fields')["nf_calories"] + ' Calories' + '</li>'
            }, this);
            this.$list.html(wordhtml);

        }
    });
    var app = new App();
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Food Guide App</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="text-center bg-black">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1>Interactive Food Guide</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-blue">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h2>Food Search</h2>
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/my-food-guide-plate.jpg" alt="food plate photo">
                    <a name="foodsearch"></a>
                    <h4>Look up food here:</h4>
                    <input type="text" id="searchBox"> <br/><br/>
                    <p id="instruct"></p>
                    <ul class="spacefood" id="listing"></ul>
                    <a href="#foodtrack">Go to food tracking</a>
                    <p>
                        Go to:
                        <a href="#breakfastrack">Breakfast</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <a href="#lunchtrack">Lunch</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <a href="#dinnertrack">Dinner</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <a href="#snacktrack">Snack</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 top-space bottom-space">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/foods.jpg" alt="foods">
                    <a name="foodtrack"></a>
                    <h2>Foods Tracked</h2>
                    <ul class="top-space spacetracked" id="tracked"></ul>
                    <p id="total"><strong> total calories:</strong> <span>0</span></p>
                    <a href="#foodsearch">Go to food search</a>
                    <p>
                        Go to:
                        <a href="#breakfastrack">Breakfast</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <a href="#lunchtrack">Lunch</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <a href="#dinnertrack">Dinner</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <a href="#snacktrack">Snack</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bg-white">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <a name="breakfastrack"></a>
                    <h1>Breakfast</h1>
                    <ul class="spacetracked" id="breakfast"></ul>
                    <p id="totalbreak"><strong> total calories:</strong> <span>0</span></p>
                    <a href="#foodsearch">Return to food search</a>
                    <p><a href="#foodtrack">Return to food tracking</a></p>
                    <p>
                        Go to:
                        <a href="#breakfastrack">Breakfast</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <a href="#lunchtrack">Lunch</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <a href="#dinnertrack">Dinner</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <a href="#snacktrack">Snack</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/breakfast-meal.jpg" alt="breakfast plate photo">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bg-blue">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <a name="lunchtrack"></a>
                    <h1>Lunch</h1>
                    <ul class="spacetracked" id="lunch"></ul>
                    <p id="totalunch"><strong> total calories:</strong> <span>0</span></p>
                    <a href="#foodsearch">Return to food search</a>
                    <p><a href="#foodtrack">Return to food tracking</a></p>
                    <p>
                        Go to:
                        <a href="#breakfastrack">Breakfast</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <a href="#lunchtrack">Lunch</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <a href="#dinnertrack">Dinner</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <a href="#snacktrack">Snack</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/lunch-meal.jpg" alt="lunch plate photo">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bg-white">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <a name="dinnertrack"></a>
                    <h1>Dinner</h1>
                    <ul class="spacetracked" id="dinner"></ul>
                    <p id="totaldinner"><strong> total calories:</strong> <span>0</span></p>
                    <a href="#foodsearch">Return to food search</a>
                    <p><a href="#foodtrack">Return to food tracking</a></p>
                    <p>
                        Go to:
                        <a href="#breakfastrack">Breakfast</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <a href="#lunchtrack">Lunch</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <a href="#dinnertrack">Dinner</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <a href="#snacktrack">Snack</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/dinner-meal.jpg" alt="dinner plate photo">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bg-blue">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <a name="snacktrack"></a>
                    <h1>Snack</h1>
                    <ul class="spacetracked" id="snack"></ul>
                    <p id="totalsnack"><strong> total calories:</strong> <span>0</span></p>
                    <a href="#foodsearch">Return to food search</a>
                    <p><a href="#foodtrack">Return to food tracking</a></p>
                    <p>
                        Go to:
                        <a href="#breakfastrack">Breakfast</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <a href="#lunchtrack">Lunch</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <a href="#dinnertrack">Dinner</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <a href="#snacktrack">Snack</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/snack-meal.jpg" alt="snack plate photo">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Backbone and Underscore -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <!-- apps functionality -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Firebase -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.9/firebase.js"></script>
    <!-- BackboneFire -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/backbonefire/0.5.1/backbonefire.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should go with require.js or almond.js just google for it you will get a lot pages

Answer (score 1):

Basically, rather than having one link to the app.js file in index.html, you would have to include every file in the right order in index.html. You could structure your folders like so:

```
/js
  /models
  /collections
  /views
```

In your `/collections` folder you would place your collections, models in the `/models` folder and so on. A collection could be called something like AllFoodsCollection.js and BreakfastCollection.js. Then you reference them all in you index.html. Remember to have you pieces in the right order.

```
<script src="js/models/FoodModel.js"></script>    
<script src="js/collections/AllFoodsCollection.js"></script>
<script src="js/collections/BreakfastCollection.js"></script>
```

It could help you a lot if you used a build system like Gulp or Grunt. You could get an easy start by using [Google's Web Starter Kit](https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit).

It also looks like you would get a lot out of reading some proper tutorials on how to structure your backbone code. For instance, you really don't need all of those collections when all you are changing is the url property. You could have one collection:

```
var FoodCollection = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
    model: Food,
    collectionType: '',
    url: function() { 
        "https://blinding-torch-8751.firebaseio.com/" + this.collectionType;
    }
});
```

Then instantiate a collection like so:

```
var breakfastCollection = new FoodCollection({collectionType: 'breakfast'});
```

There is a great book on how to use backbone, with lots of tips on how to structure you code, here: http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/.

Good luck with the health tracker app :).

Comment: I had the idea of creating one collection but could not instantiate with a url property so I had no choice but to do it this way. I also did research on many sites on how to instantiate with a url property but it was said to be not possible.

Comment: I tried this way of instantiation in your example it doesn't work

Comment: @RSB, Maybe try this:
`FoodCollection = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
  model: Food,
  collectionType: '',
  firebase: new Firebase("https://blinding-torch-8751.firebaseio.com/"+this.collectionType),
});`